# Java: Find the index of a String in a list

Tags: java, list

I have a list:

```
public static  List<String> codes = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(
            "Zero",
            "One"
            )); //Etc..
```

I want to be able to find the number of a `String`'s position when I type it. For instance, if I type `One`, I want the program to print out `1`. Currently, I can only do the reverse by using `codes.get();`

Correction: I want the program to print out the position of the String in the list. `Zero` has the position `0`, if I do `codes.get(0);` I get `Zero`. But how do I do the reverse?

Is there a way to smoothly do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unclear, do you want the _index_ of the String or do you want the String matching the english name of the number?

Comment: @Tunaki `Get element by index` vs `get index by element` :)

Comment: The `List` api is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reverse of `codes.get()` is  [`indexOf(Object obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) method

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.

```
codes.indexOf("One");
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.